# How to set datagrid columnheader to show both icon and text?

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid, columnheader

I have a datagrid in my WPF app and I want to show a redlight icon on some columns to demonstrate that the column is missing some data. This is my window resource in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RedTemp">
    <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/red.png"
           Height="9"
           Width="9"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</DataTemplate>
```

and this is how I call it from code behind:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn y in grid.Columns)
{
    if (Missing== 1)
    {
        y.HeaderTemplate = FindResource("RedTemp") as DataTemplate;
    }              
}
```

But when I run the app, the datagrid shows red lights on columns but the Column Header Text disappears!

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your DataTemplate to have a TextBlock with your text, something like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RedTemp">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  />
        <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/red.png"
               Height="9"
               Width="9"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Grid.Column="1"
               />
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I haven't tested this though.

*Edit:* Added a Panel around 2 UI Elements.

Comment: You should have a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7943795/197371) if you want a better answer today. I have to leave now.